# Android Studio: Runtime errors not displaying

Tags: android

I've just switched to Android Studio and I'm having a hard time debugging at runtime, my app crashes on startup and I don't know why, I only get the following error:

```
ddmlib: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:342)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:521)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:847)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:815)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:633)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:46)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:592)

ddms: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:195)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:66)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:772)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

ddms: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:195)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:66)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:772)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

It feels like the IDE isn't giving me the correct runtime errors, do I have to set this up somehow?